# Custom tick step on QCustomPlot - QT

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

Im new in QCustomPlot but I am not able to create custom size of TickStep.

Right now, I have this plot, (time is from 6:00 to 6:00 another day).

[image]

And what is my desired X axis label:

[image]

I tried to play with setTickStep but without any success.

```
    QVector<double> x(96), y(96); 

     for (int i=0; i<95; ++i)
     {
       x[i] = i*900+22500;
       y[i] = someValues loaded from db 

     }

     ui->customPlot->addGraph();

     ui->customPlot->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(239, 239, 239, 255)));
     ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

     ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(21600, 108000);
     ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
     ui->customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("h:mm");

     //ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickStep(7200);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed one thing before setting a custom tick step. The feature, called: *auto tick step* is enabled by default on the axes so you need to disable it first.

```
QVector<double> x(96), y(96);

for (int i=0; i<95; ++i)
{
  x[i] = i*900+22500;
  y[i] = i;  // some values not from database
}
ui->customPlot->addGraph();
ui->customPlot->setBackground(QBrush(QColor(239, 239, 239, 255)));
ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(21600, 108000);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
ui->customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("h:mm");

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setAutoTickStep(false);   // <-- disable to use your own value

ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickStep(7200);
```

The result with and without the additional line:

[image]